# Fabric8 failed to watch custom resource in the junit test

Tags: fabric8

I am trying to learn how to test custom resource watcher in the Fabric8, I follow the example from this link https://github.com/r0haaaan/kubernetes-mockserver-demo/blob/master/src/test/java/io/fabric8/demo/kubernetes/mockserver/CustomResourceMockTest.java

My custom resource is "UserACL", I am using Java junit5, this is my fabric8 version.
implementation group: 'io.fabric8', name: 'kubernetes-client', version: '5.9.0'
implementation group: 'io.fabric8', name: 'kubernetes-api', version: '3.0.12'
testImplementation group: 'io.fabric8', name: 'kubernetes-server-mock', version: '5.9.0'

This test case failed, seem there is no any WatchEvent emitted, so countLatch never count down.

Could anybody help take a look and point out what's wrong here? Anything is missing in the following code. I appreciate it in advanced.

```
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.Condition;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.KubernetesResourceList;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.ObjectMetaBuilder;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.WatchEvent;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.WatchEventBuilder;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.CustomResource;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Watch;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Watcher;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.WatcherException;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.MixedOperation;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.Resource;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.server.mock.KubernetesServer;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.internal.KubernetesDeserializer;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.model.annotation.Group;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.model.annotation.Kind;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.model.annotation.Version;
import io.vertx.junit5.VertxExtension;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;

public class TestKafkaHelperUtilFourth {

  @Rule
  public KubernetesServer server = new KubernetesServer(true, true);

  @Test
  @DisplayName("Should watch all custom resources")
  public void testWatch() throws InterruptedException {
    // Given
    server.expect().withPath("/apis/custom.example.com/v1/namespaces/default/useracls?watch=true")
        .andUpgradeToWebSocket()
        .open()
        .waitFor(10L)
        .andEmit(new WatchEvent(getUserACL("test-resource"), "ADDED"))
        .waitFor(10L)
        .andEmit(new WatchEventBuilder()
            .withNewStatusObject()
            .withMessage("410 - the event requested is outdated")
            .withCode(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_GONE)
            .endStatusObject()
            .build()).done().always();
    KubernetesClient client = server.getClient();
    MixedOperation<
        UserACL,
            KubernetesResourceList<UserACL>,
            Resource<UserACL>>
        userAclClient = client.resources(UserACL.class);

    // When
    CountDownLatch eventRecieved = new CountDownLatch(1);
    KubernetesDeserializer.registerCustomKind("custom.example.com/v1", "UserACL", UserACL.class);
    Watch watch = userAclClient.inNamespace("default").watch(new Watcher<UserACL>() {
      @Override
      public void eventReceived(Action action, UserACL userAcl) {
        if (action.name().contains("ADDED"))
          eventRecieved.countDown();
      }

      @Override
      public void onClose(WatcherException e) { }
    });

    // Then
    eventRecieved.await(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Assertions.assertEquals(0, eventRecieved.getCount());
    watch.close();
  }

  private UserACL getUserACL(String resourceName) {
    UserACLSpec spec = new UserACLSpec();
    spec.setUserName("test-user-name");

    UserACL createdUserACL = new UserACL();
    createdUserACL.setMetadata(
        new ObjectMetaBuilder().withName(resourceName).build());
    createdUserACL.setSpec(spec);

    Condition condition = new Condition();
    condition.setMessage("Last reconciliation succeeded");
    condition.setReason("Successful");
    condition.setStatus("True");
    condition.setType("Successful");
    UserACLStatus status = new UserACLStatus();
    status.setCondition(new Condition[]{condition});
    createdUserACL.setStatus(status);

    return createdUserACL;
  }

  @Group("custom.example.com")
  @Version("v1")
  @Kind("UserACL")
  public static final class UserACL
      extends CustomResource<UserACLSpec, UserACLStatus> {

  }
  public static final class UserACLSpec {
    private String userName;

    public UserACLSpec() {}

    public String getUserName() {
      return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
      this.userName = userName;
    }
  }
  public static final class UserACLStatus {
    Condition[] condition;

    public UserACLStatus() {};

    public Condition[] getCondition() {
      return condition;
    }

    public void setCondition(Condition[] condition) {
      this.condition = condition;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: There is no error. In fact test case failed. CountDDownLatch eventRecieved has not been down, that means there is no event that has been emitted. Any ideas how to fix it? Or you can import the above code to try in your test environment.

Comment: I am wondering the purpose of "KubernetesDeserializer.registerCustomKind" in the code, is it used to trigger to emit an event? could I remove it?

Comment: It used to be required in older KubernetesClient versions to register CustomResource model in Kubernetes Deserializer. In recent versions, it shouldn't be required anymore

Comment: Hi @RohanKumar , could you do me a favor how to fix the above issue?

Comment: Give me some time, let me try it after work.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I was getting stuck for a while. Because I wrote some  CR watcher, I have to use this way to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code; after resolving these problems I was able to get test working:

1. You're setting MockServer expectations using `server.expect()` for mocking watch call. But you've initialized KubernetesMockServer to enable CRUD mode (this doesn't require any expectations). You need to do this instead (see `false` being passed as second argument which disables CRUD mode):

```java
  @Rule
  public KubernetesServer server = new KubernetesServer(true, false);
```

2. In Watch expectations path I can see that UserACL resource is a namespaced one. All Namespaced scope resources in KubernetesClient must implement `io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.Namespaced` interface:

```java
  @Group("custom.example.com")
  @Version("v1")
  @Kind("UserACL")
  public static final class UserACL extends CustomResource<UserACLSpec, UserACLStatus> implements Namespaced { }
```

3. (Optional) I'm not sure whether you're using JUnit4 or JUnit5, I also had to update `org.junit.Test` to `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` and also add `@EnableRuleMigrationSupport` annotation in order to run this test on my JUnit5 project:

```java
@EnableRuleMigrationSupport
public class TestKafkaHelperUtilFourth {
```

After making these changes, test seemed to run okay for me:

```
$ mvn -Dtest=io.fabric8.demo.kubernetes.mockserver.TestKafkaHelperUtilFourth test


[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running io.fabric8.demo.kubernetes.mockserver.TestKafkaHelperUtilFourth
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
जुल॰ 08, 2022 10:29:31 अपराह्न okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[49697] starting to accept connections
जुल॰ 08, 2022 10:29:31 अपराह्न okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$3 processOneRequest
INFO: MockWebServer[49697] received request: GET /apis/custom.example.com/v1/namespaces/default/useracls?watch=true HTTP/1.1 and responded: HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
जुल॰ 08, 2022 10:29:31 अपराह्न okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2 acceptConnections
INFO: MockWebServer[49697] done accepting connections: Socket closed
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.779 s - in io.fabric8.demo.kubernetes.mockserver.TestKafkaHelperUtilFourth
```

Comment: Hi @RohanKumar, in my environment, after I update my code with your comments, it still failed. I suspect some library version might be different from yours. Could you paste or show what your library version for kubernetes-client, kubernetes-server-mock?

Comment: and I am using Java version 11

Comment: I copy pasted your test in my project. It's here https://github.com/r0haaaan/kubernetes-mockserver-demo/blob/stackoverflow-72904389/src/test/java/io/fabric8/demo/kubernetes/mockserver/TestKafkaHelperUtilFourth.java

Comment: Thank you, I ran your test case successfully. I will double check my test env.

Comment: It works now. Big thanks to you @RohanKumar. one more question, KubernetesServer server = new KubernetesServer(true, false), the first parameter is "true", what does it mean? for the 2nd parameter, what does it mean "CRUD mode"? Or where could I find it usage?

Comment: First parameter is whether to use `https` or not. Crud mode means MockServer would behave like real Kubernetes Cluster; You don't need to set any expectations. You can find examples here: https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/kubernetes-tests/src/test/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/mock/ConfigMapCrudTest.java